# How I check $mdDialog is Open?

Tags: angularjs, mddialog

Is there a way to check $mdDialog is Open or not?

My friend suggest me to use $mdDialog(componentId).isOpen()

But don't know, "What is **componentId** here"

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5071

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an HTML/CSS based solution:

```
angular.element(document.body).hasClass('md-dialog-is-showing')
```

It is working as expected for me!
Source: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5071

Thanks Guys!!

Comment: Worth noting, as you're posting it here, that this method will not be able to check for individual dialogues as it'll return a boolean if at least one dialog is open, however you may have more than one open at any time. PS this is a JavaScript/CSS solution not HTML.